# Наибольший палиндром

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, python-3.6

ограничение по времени на тест 1 секунда
ограничение по памяти на тест 256 мегабайт

В заданной строке найдите длину наибольшей подстроки (отрезка подряд идущих символов строки), которая является палиндромом, то есть одинаково читается слева направо и справа налево. Гарантируется, что заданная строка состоит только из строчных латинских букв.

Входные данные
В единственной строке входных данных записана заданная последовательность строчных латинских букв s (1≤|s|≤1000).

Выходные данные
Выведите одно целое положительное число — длину наибольшей подстроки-палиндрома.

Примеры

входные данные
a
выходные данные
1

входные данные
zrgttg
выходные данные
4

входные данные
abacaba
выходные данные
7

```
a,c,ma=input(),'',0
v=0
w=len(a)
for i in range(w):
        for j in range(w):
                c=''
                for k in range(i,j+1):
                        c+=a[k]
                if c==c[::-1]:
                        if len(c)>ma:
                                ma=len(c)


print(ma)
```

Данная программа не проходит по времени. Подскажите как ее ускорить?

Comment: Почитайте вот эту статейку: https://habr.com/ru/post/276195/

Comment: у меня ваша программа выполнилась за 0.0009999275207519531 секунд при вводе 012345678909876543210.

Comment: @n1tr0xs А вы запустите для строки длиной 1000 символов...

Comment: Мне кажется, но в большинства тестирующих систем есть проблема с замером скорости в python ~10^6 операций за секунду, но самое обидное в том что на С++ этот код пройдёт все тесты, так как там проходит ~10^8 операций в секунду... Но все же, ваш код работает за время O(n^3), такое тут не прокатит.

Comment: Да просто за квадрат в лоб. Перебор среднего элемента палиндрома и в длину пока можно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно решить эту задачу (тест с 1000 символов дал подходящий результат):

```
def findPal(string):
    def findOdd(string):
        max=1
        for Middle in range(len(string)):
            leftBorder = Middle - 1
            rightBorder = Middle + 1
            while(leftBorder >= 0 and rightBorder<len(string) and string[leftBorder] == string[rightBorder]):
                new_str = string[leftBorder:rightBorder+1]
                if len(new_str) >max: max=len(new_str)
                leftBorder-=1
                rightBorder+=1
        return max

    def findEven(string):
        max=1
        for Middle in range(len(string)):
            leftBorder = Middle
            rightBorder = Middle + 1
            while(leftBorder >= 0 and rightBorder < len(string) and string[leftBorder] == string[rightBorder]):
                new_str = string[leftBorder:rightBorder+1]
                if len(new_str) >max: max=len(new_str)
                leftBorder-=1
                rightBorder+=1
        return max

    return max([findOdd(string), findEven(string)])
string=input('Enter string: ')
print(findPal(string))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.pypys3", line 28, in <module>
    print(findPal(string))
NameError: name 'string' is not defined

Comment: Вот это выдает.

Comment: string это ваша строка, которую вводят. Забыл указать